# Use external constructor of base class in extended class __init__

Tags: python, inheritance

Here is the setup:

There is an external library that has a class called BaseClass

```
class BaseClass():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    def base(self):
        print("base class, x= {}".format(self.x))
```

There is another external library with a function that constructs BaseClasses

```
def constructor_fn(x):
    # do some cool things
    return BaseClass(x)
```

I want to extend BaseClass for my own uses, but I want to make use of the constructor_fn that makes instances of BaseClass, but I am not sure there is a pattern for doing it.

```
class ExtendedClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, x):
        base_instance = constructor_fn(x)
        # ?????
    def extended(self):
        print("cool new extended function")
```

Is there any way I can use constructor_fn in my ExtendedClass? Keep in mind that constructor_fn and BaseClass are both in external libraries and I can't edit them.

I was thinking maybe of iterating through all properties in `base_instance` and assigning them to `self` but that seems... bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can *try* to monkey patch:

```
import external_lib
external_lib.BaseClass = ExtendedClass
import another_lib

instance = another_lib.constructor_fn()
```

This is hackey, obviously. And may have all sorts of unintended side-effects.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `constructor_fn` in [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__), then change the [`__class__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#instance.__class__) attribute of the instance that's created. This seems a bit hacky, and I've never used it myself, but as long as no parts of `ExtendedClass` are used in construction, it should work.

Here's a minimal example:

```
class BaseClass:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{type(self).__name__}({self.x!r})'

def constructor_fn(x):
    return BaseClass(x + ' fn')

class ExtendedClass(BaseClass):
    def __new__(cls, x):
        inst = constructor_fn(x)
        inst.__class__ = cls
        return inst

    def __init__(self, _x):
        """Parameter "_x" is ignored since it's consumed by "__new__"."""
        self.x += ' ext'

for constructor in BaseClass, constructor_fn, ExtendedClass:
    print(constructor('base'))
```

Output:

```
BaseClass('base')
BaseClass('base fn')
ExtendedClass('base fn ext')
```